# Google App Script - LockService Function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am quite new to Google App Script. I understand what `getScriptLock()` does but I do not understand what `waitlock()` does. Could someone please help me understand how I can use this function?

Answer (score 0):

It attempts to aquire the lock, timing out with an exception after the provided number of milliseconds. This method is the same as `tryLock(timeoutInMillis)` except that it throws an exception when the lock could not be aquired instead of returning false.

Refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock#waitLock(Integer)) document.

Comment: Thank you, what would stop it from acquiring a lock? what would something like this be used for?